# Usage of the phrase "the statement"

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Is it okay to say "Is the statement below correct?" to mean that "Are the four sentences below correct?"? or do I have to say "Are the four statements below correct?", since the phrase "the statement" can only refer to a single sentence? In other words, can "statement"(i.e. not "statements") have two or more sentences, not just one?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A statement can be as many sentences as you want, as long as it's one idea:

Is the below statement correct?

> The president is the head of state. He runs the country. He is elected by voters.

If any part of the statement is incorrect the whole statement is incorrect. In other words if any sentence is not true, this makes the whole statement false.

But it is seen as ONE statement.

Comment: The following is the email I sent: **"Hi John, is the statement below correct?: "In heaven, we will love each human completely. In heaven, we will love each human equally, that is, we will not love one more than another. The love that we will have in heaven for everyone will be warm and selfless. In heaven, however, God will always be the principal object of our love because in heaven our love for God will be the precise reason why we love others." Thanks,"**  would you say that the 4 sentences that I inquired about is considered as a one statement because they talk about one idea?

Comment: Please edit into your question. Comments are temporary and not necessarily retained with posts. See [How do comments work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work).

Comment: Yes, those 4 sentences are equal to 1 statement.